# What happens when we cancel apt-get install manually or due to network failure

Tags: networking, apt, aptitude

hi today I was installing mongodb using apt-get its 114 mb download , when apt-get was running  I lost network connection so downloading stopped so cancelled it using Ctrl + c . Later when my connection resumed I started apt-get install again but this time it showed it needs to downloadd 109 mb instead of 114 mb ,but this time too my internet connection was slow so I cancelled it using  Ctrl + c .

So my question is how does apt-get work ? what happens to data downloaded if there is network error or users cancels installation ? do I need to clean previous incomplete downloads before trying to install again ? how do I resume installation again ?? how do I start a clean installation ?

pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does apt-get work ?

- `apt-get` is the command-line tool for handling packages, and may be
     considered the user's "back-end" to other tools using the APT library.
     Several "front-end" interfaces exist, such as aptitude, synaptic
     and wajig.

> what happens to data downloaded if there is network error or users cancels installation ?

- If a network error or user cancels the package installation, the operation will be canceled and the partially downloaded packages are stored inside `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory.

> do I need to clean previous incomplete downloads before trying to install again ?

- No, it's not compulsory to clean the previous incomplete downloads.

> how do I resume installation again ?

- Add `-f` parameter or flag after `apt-get` like `sudo apt-get install -f <package-name>`. It will resumes the installation.

> how do I start a clean installation ?

- Try these commands, it will remove all unused packages and will erase the downloaded archive files.

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- Now start a fresh installation of packages.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install <package-name>
  ```